# jQuery/Javascript - Set click action on image based on it's src

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I have some images which I cannot add IDs or links to within the HTML.

I am wondering if there is a way to write some script that applies a link to an image based on it's src.

For example,

If the image src is "http://www.my-image/img1.jpg", link it to X.
If the image src is "http://www.my-image/img2.jpg", link it to Y.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

src is an attribute of the img tag.  jQuery has a wide range of attribute selectors:

All images with a src attribute value equal to "myPic.jpg"

```
$("[src='myPic.jpg']")
```

All elements with a src attribute value ending with ".jpg"

```
$("[src$='.jpg']")
```

All elements with a src attribute value starting with "myPic"

```
$("[src^='myPic']")
```

All elements with a src attribute value containing the word "myPic"

```
$("[src*='myPic']")
```

All elements with a src attribute value not equal to "myPic.jpg"

```
$("[src!='myPic.jpg']")
```

Src: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

So to answer your question, you can select your image(s) with:

```
$("img[src='http://www.my-image/img1.jpg']").attr('onclick', 'window.location="X"');
```

and

```
$("img[src='http://www.my-image/img2.jpg']").attr('onclick', 'window.location="Y"');
```

Alternatively it may make more sense to just look at the file name ending:

```
$("img[src$='img1.jpg']").attr('onclick', 'window.location="X"');
```

and

```
$("img[src$='img2.jpg']").attr('onclick', 'window.location="Y"');
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful info. Really appreciate it.